# Duration to return the request for a endpoint call

Tags: java, microservices

I need to be clear about something.  If a microservice has an SLA of 10 seconds for a request round­trip. Does it mean I get 10s to return the request?

Comment: Ok, I don't know and this is the reason I asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request roundtrip time RTT is time between 
A- client makes request to server  B- client gets response  back from server

Now this time RTT includes your server response time + network delays based on many factors like distance,network hops, traffic congestion.